# Tint size not correct in Xamarin Forms with .NETStandard 2.0

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, androiddesignsupport

I created a new xamarin forms project with .NET Standard 2.0 and in the sample i changed the label to Button and added the background color. While the button is clicked the ripple animation is shown small and concentrated to the top left corner and not the entire button width and height

```
<Button Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Lime"  />
```

Is there anything we need to do to make the ripple animation correct.

Please see the image attached.

[image]

Comment: I've heard about this issue happening only on some devices. I bet it's a manufacturer's SO version specific implementation... Still in search of a solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the extra tint animation part. Then you have to write custom render class for Button in Android platfrom. Please check the sample code

```
    assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TintableButton), typeof(TintableButtonRenderer))]
namespace XamTest.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class TintableButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var control = e.NewElement as TintableButton;
            if (control != null)
            {
                if (control.TintColor != Xamarin.Forms.Color.Default)
                {
                    var androidColor = control.TintColor.ToAndroid();
                    Control.Background.SetColorFilter(androidColor, PorterDuff.Mode.Src);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call this custom control in UI.

```
 <Grid>
    <controls:TintableButton Text="Test" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
   </Grid>
```

Comment: Is TintColor a custom property i tried setting  Control.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent, PorterDuff.Mode.Src); but of no use it still shows the same distorted tint

Comment: did you check the style in android project? what is style you are using for button tint may be it's getting from there. for details check this link- https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/08/coloring-buttons-with-themeoverlays-background-tints.html

Comment: Currently i am not styling my buttons separately my app base theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

Comment: My custom button in this case(TintableButton) is a normal basic xamarin.forms.button

Comment: I'm unable to get this issues in android latest version with updated Xamarin form package. apart from this if you want to actual create button with different UI style. You have to work with theme and style in android project.

Comment: This issue is specific to samsung devices in other devices(nexus and pixel) i am not getting this issue?